# Hide field with html hidden div and JS Var

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, calculator

I am trying to hide HTML fields using hidden in a div with Javascript.

HTML and JS:

```
<div class="fieldcontainer">
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="4" id="tdee" name"tdee" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo TDEE" form="fbday" required autocomplete="off"/>
<label>Spesa calorica</label>
</div>

<div class="container_level">
  <select class="target" id="target_select" form="fbday" name="target">
    <option value="0">Stile di vita / Attività fisica</option>
    <option id="mass1" name="radsa" value="5">mass1</option>
    <option id="mass2" name="radsa" value="10">mass2</option>
    <option id="mass3" name="radsa" value="15">mass3</option>
    <option id="def1" name="radsa" value="10">def1</option>
    <option id="def2" name="radsa" value="15">def2</option>
    <option id="def3" name="radsa" value="20">def3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!---Fabbisogno Giornaliero--->

<div id="fbbday0" class="results" hidden>
<input type="text" form="fbday" class="result-field" id="dayli_intake_mass" name="dayli_intake"
placeholder="Fabbisogno giornaliero / 0.000 Kcal" min="1" readonly/>
<label class="mts-label"></label>
</div>

<div id="fbbday1" class="results" hidden>
<input type="text" form="fbday" class="result-field" id="dayli_intake_def" name="dayli_intake"
placeholder="Fabbisogno giornaliero / 0.000 Kcal" min="1" readonly/>
<label class="mts-label"></label>
</div>

<form action="" id="fbday">
</form>

<button name="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
<button id="reset" onclick="resetFields()">Reset</button>
```

```
calculate = function()
{
    var tdee = document.getElementById('tdee').value;
    var target = document.querySelector('#target_select option:checked').value;
    
    var dayli_intake_mass = ((+target)/100*(+tdee)+(+tdee));
    var kcal = "Devi assumere "+dayli_intake_mass.toLocaleString('it-IT',{maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal"; document.getElementById('dayli_intake_mass').value = kcal;
    
    var dayli_intake_def = ((+tdee)-(+target)/100*(+tdee));
    var kcal = "Devi assumere "+dayli_intake_def.toLocaleString('it-IT',{maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal"; document.getElementById('dayli_intake_def').value = kcal;
    
//This is Target Radio Selection//
 var mass1 = document.getElementById('mass1').value;
 var mass2 = document.getElementById('mass2').value;
 var mass3 = document.getElementById('mass3').value;
 var def1 = document.getElementById('def1').value;
 var def2 = document.getElementById('def2').value;
 var def3 = document.getElementById('def3').value;    

//This is HideShow Result/
var trgt = document.querySelector('#target_select option:checked').value;
document.getElementById('fbbday0').hidden = trgt !== '5';
document.getElementById('fbbday0').hidden = trgt !== '10';
document.getElementById('fbbday0').hidden = trgt !== '15';
document.getElementById('fbbday1').hidden = trgt !== '10';
document.getElementById('fbbday1').hidden = trgt !== '15';
document.getElementById('fbbday1').hidden = trgt !== '20';

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/w1nLbhxv/151/

When I click on mass1 and def2 it works correctly, while on others it does not work, therefore perpetually hiding the result field. I suppose it's the fault of equal values, but I'm not sure.

1.I would like to show the result of this: var dayli_intake_mass = ((+ target) / 100 * (+ tdee) + (+ tdee)); only when mass1, mass2 or mass3 is selected.
Otherwise

2.I would like to show the result of this: var dayli_intake_def = ((+ tdee) - (+ target) / 100 * (+ tdee)); only when def1, def2 or def3 is selected.
So, the mass1, mass2 and mass3 selection should show dayli_intake_mass

While the selection def1, def2 and def3 should show dayli_intake_def

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two divs are not necessary, given my understanding of the use case. You can have on div rendering result depending on what has been selected.

```
 <div class="fieldcontainer">
        <input
            oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
            type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="4" id="tdee" name"tdee" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo TDEE"
            form="fbday" required autocomplete="off" />
        <label>Spesa calorica</label>
    </div>

    <div class="container_level">
        <select class="target" id="target_select" form="fbday" name="target">
            <option value="0">Stile di vita / Attività fisica</option>
            <option id="mass1" name="radsa" value="5">mass1</option>
            <option id="mass2" name="radsa" value="10">mass2</option>
            <option id="mass3" name="radsa" value="15">mass3</option>
            <option id="def1" name="radsa" value="10">def1</option>
            <option id="def2" name="radsa" value="15">def2</option>
            <option id="def3" name="radsa" value="20">def3</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!---Fabbisogno Giornaliero--->

    <div id="fbbday0" class="results" hidden>
        <input type="text" form="fbday" class="result-field" id="dairyInTakeResult" name="dayli_intake" readonly />
        <label class="mts-label"></label>
    </div>

    <form action="" id="fbday">
    </form>

    <button name="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    <button id="reset" onclick="resetFields()">Reset</button>
```

Edited HTML

```
 <div class="fieldcontainer">
        <input
            oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
            type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="4" id="tdee" name"tdee" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo TDEE"
            form="fbday" required autocomplete="off" />
        <label>Spesa calorica</label>
    </div>

    <div class="container_level">
        <select class="target" id="target_select" form="fbday" name="target">
            <option value="0">Stile di vita / Attività fisica</option>
            <option class="mass" id="mass1" name="radsa" value="5">mass1</option>
            <option class="mass" id="mass2" name="radsa" value="10">mass2</option>
            <option class="mass" id="mass3" name="radsa" value="15">mass3</option>
            <option class="def" id="def1" name="radsa" value="10">def1</option>
            <option class="def" id="def2" name="radsa" value="15">def2</option>
            <option class="def" id="def3" name="radsa" value="20">def3</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!---Fabbisogno Giornaliero--->

    <div id="fbbday0" class="results" hidden>
        <input type="text" form="fbday" class="result-field" id="dairyInTakeResult" name="dayli_intake" readonly />
        <label class="mts-label"></label>
    </div>

    <form action="" id="fbday">
    </form>

    <button name="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    <button id="reset" onclick="resetFields()">Reset</button>
```

```
    calculate = function () {
        var tdee = document.getElementById('tdee').value;
        var target = document.querySelector('#target_select option:checked').value;
    
        var dayli_intake_mass = ((+target) / 100 * (+tdee) + (+tdee));

        var kcal = "Devi assumere " + dayli_intake_mass.toLocaleString('it-IT', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 }) + " Kcal"; 
        document.getElementById('dairyInTakeResult').value = kcal;
    
        var dayli_intake_def = ((+tdee) - (+target) / 100 * (+tdee));

        kcal = "Devi assumere " + dayli_intake_def.toLocaleString('it-IT', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 }) + " Kcal"; 
        document.getElementById('dairyInTakeResult').value = kcal;
    
        //This is HideShow Result/
        document.getElementById('dairyInTakeResult').value = kcal;

        var trgt = document.querySelector('#target_select option:checked').value;

        if (trgt === "0" ){
            document.getElementById('fbbday0').hidden = true
            document.getElementById('dairyInTakeResult').value = '';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('fbbday0').hidden = false
        } 
    }     calculate = function () {
        var tdee = document.getElementById('tdee').value;
        var target = document.querySelector('#target_select option:checked').value;
    
        var dayli_intake_mass = ((+target) / 100 * (+tdee) + (+tdee));

        var kcal = "Devi assumere " + dayli_intake_mass.toLocaleString('it-IT', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 }) + " Kcal"; 

        var dayli_intake_def = ((+tdee) - (+target) / 100 * (+tdee));

        kcal = "Devi assumere " + dayli_intake_def.toLocaleString('it-IT', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 }) + " Kcal"; 
    
   
        document.getElementById('dairyInTakeResult').value = kcal;
        var trgt = document.querySelector('#target_select option:checked').value;

        //If header selected, zero and hide the result input, else show
        if (trgt === "0" ){
            document.getElementById('fbbday0').hidden = true
            document.getElementById('dairyInTakeResult').value = '';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('fbbday0').hidden = false
        } 
    }
```

Edited JS

```
 calculate = function () {
        var tdee = document.getElementById('tdee').value;
        var target = document.querySelector('#target_select option:checked').value;
        var optionClass = document.querySelector('#target_select option:checked').className;
    
        document.getElementById('dairyInTakeResult').value = calculateCalorie(tdee, target, optionClass);
        var trgt = document.querySelector('#target_select option:checked').value;

        //If header selected, zero and hide the result input, else show
        if (trgt === "0" ){
            document.getElementById('fbbday0').hidden = true
            document.getElementById('dairyInTakeResult').value = '';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('fbbday0').hidden = false
        } 
    }  

    function calculateCalorie(tdee, target, optionClass){
        var dairyCalorie;
        if (optionClass === 'mass'){
            dairyCalorie = ((+target) / 100 * (+tdee) + (+tdee));
            return "Devi assumere " + dairyCalorie.toLocaleString('it-IT', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 }) + " Kcal"; 

        } else if (optionClass === 'def'){
            dairyCalorie = ((+tdee) - (+target) / 100 * (+tdee));
            return "Devi assumere " + dairyCalorie.toLocaleString('it-IT', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 }) + " Kcal"; 
        } else {
            alert('Please make a selection');
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic! It works perfectly. I have read the code and it is different than what I had done. I would never have gotten there on my own, I have very little knowledge in programming. Thanks again.

One last thing: can I contact you privately for some job applications? I would like to pay someone to develop some functions that I need to work.

Comment: Oops ... I only realized now that the calculations are not correct.

For example: if I enter 2000 and choose mas1 (+ 5% value), the result is 1,900 (subtract instead of adding). All mas values add the percentage to the input, while all defs subtract the percentage.

This did not happen before, it worked correctly. How can I solve ?

Comment: Basically I understand that your code always executes the variable var dayli_intake_def which is the subtraction, while the variable var dayli_intake_mass is never executed.

Comment: I had noticed that component. I have made changes to the code. Kindly check

Comment: @EmanueleDaniele I agreeable to your proposal